# How do I get the American Flag back on my menu bar?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm new to Macs and got a 2011 MacBook Pro a few weeks ago and when I first set it up there was an American Flag on my menu bar.  Somehow it has disappeared and I can't figure out how to get it back.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in the *Language and Text*, under *Input source*, you need to select one or more input sources; you also need to select *Keyboard and Character Viewer* on the top of the input source list.
As far as I know, the flag is displayed only when you select more than one input source; differently, the icon you see is a generic one.

This is the icon you see when just an input source is selected.

[image: Generic icon]

This is the icon you see when you selected two or more input sources; in this case, the selected input source is "Italian Pro."

[image: "Italian PRO" icon]

Comment: Thank you.  So it really like a menu that lets you switch between the two input languages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to your system preferences and go to language and religion or language and text. When you get there you will see a small button in the bottom that says keyboard preferences, when you get there you can choose your languages and you will have the small flag.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  It also appears to be written for macOS Sierra and not the system the OP was using in 2011.  In Sierra, you also have to check the box `Show input menu in menu bar` to display the flag but this isn't in your answer.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.  - From Review.